# Supabase using a TRIGGER or SERVER SIDE

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I have a REST endpoint in my backend that allows users to make requests. When a user calls this endpoint, the backend performs a check to verify if the user is authorized as an admin. If the user is authorized, the backend proceeds to edit a specific record in the database.

Currently, I have a requirement to track changes made to the data, so I can keep a record of which admin modified it. However, since the check and change are both handled in the backend, I'm uncertain about the best approach for logging these changes. If I use a trigger, I can log when the data is changed, but I won't have information about which admin initiated the change because the admin ID is checked within the backend and the actual modification is performed by a service role.

To address this challenge, I believe it would be helpful to handle the logging and creation of log records directly in the backend. By doing so, I would have access to the admin ID and can include it in the log record.

Comment: If the database doesn't have all the information you need to log, you cannot log it in the database. So I tend to agree.

Comment: It seems like you already have the answer.